# Cat has started drooling while sleeping...sick?

Tags: cats, behavior, health

My cat is a year and a half old - and I have had her almost that long - the last two days I have found huge wet spots on my bed, and noticed the side of my cats face was quite wet a few times, and just confirmed that it is from her drooling in her sleep (checked under her face while sleeping...big wet spot, damp face).

This has never happened before, although she is a 'sucker', and has left plenty of wet spots on clothing from sucking, but has never drooled in her sleep before. It is a lot of drool...she'll leave a spot 6 inches across on my bed from napping an hour or two.

BUT, she is eating and drinking normally, and doing all the stuff she normally does. She seems happy and is playful, active, and affectionate as normal. Not sleeping any more or less than usual.

Should I be worried?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this? My cat is going through the same thing right now. Called the vet she said unless he starts showing other symptoms then to not worry too much about it. However he is drooling so much that I’m debating on whether or not I need to take him I’m. Same thing though he’s acting fine otherwise wants to play and is eating/drinking normally

Comment: Is she old? I've had a cat who started doing it when she got into old age.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some cats, like some humans,  do this.  It may be exacerbated if they have a bit of a cold and hence are breathing through their mouth more.  But unless there are other symptoms I wouldn't worry about it; maybe mention it at the next vet appointment just to make sure.

Comment: I'm suspecting it may have something to do with the recent heatwave...except this is her second summer and I don't remember her drooling in her sleep last summer. It only worries me because it's a change from the usual. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Some cats also drool when exposed to catnip.

Answer (score 2):

Excessive drool can indicate dental problems. Can you look into her mouth? You are looking for any swelling of the gums, excessive tartar buildup, or anything that looks unusual.

Comment: Yeah, her mouth looks good, and no eating problems at all. She seems to have slowed or stopped on the drooling now. Seems she may have just been adjusting to the sudden change in temperature. She has a very thick, wooly coat on her.

Answer (score 0):

Drooling can be a symptom of toxicity associated with insecticides, such as flea treatment products. Other symptoms are loss of balance, lethargy, diarrhea, in serious cases, tremors.
It is probably not the case here, but it is good to keep this in mind if you are using such a product, in which case you should stop it and take advice from your vet.